# Comparing two algorithms on a single dataset using total cost - Which statistical test to use?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, weka, performance-testing, significance

I have to run three different kinds of comparisons between different data mining algorithms.

The only type of comparison that is problematic for is the most basic one, ***two algorithms on a single data set*** - is the problematic one for me.

I am aware of the *Diettrich (1998)* paper which refers to **McNemar** and **5x2CV** as the options of choice and states, that resampled t-test is infeasible. As the analysis forms part of a larger setup using *subsamples, 60:40 training:test-splits and total cost as performance measure*,  I cannot use those though.

***Which other options are there to evaluate the performance in this case?***

- **Sign-test:** Just counting the number of cases, where each of the two algorithms performs better and thereafter check the p-value using the binomial distribution. Problematic as very weak.
- **Wilcoxon-signed-rank-test:** As non-parametric alternative to the t-test the first one I thought of, but not mentioned in any paper for this kind of comparison, only for comparing two algorithms on several datasets using average performance result of several iterations. ***Is it infeasible and if so, why?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious difference between the two is that Wilcoxon signed rank test requires that you compute a difference between the two members of a pair and then rank these differences. If the only information you have for each member of a pair is whether the data-mining procedures guessed the class of their member correctly, then there will only be three possible signed ranks - -1, 0, 1, and the Wilcoxon signed rank test will be equivalent to the McNemar test, which is in fact simply a way of calculating an approximate tail value of the sign test. If it makes sense to compare the results from the two members of a pair but not to subtract them and get a number then again you are back with the sign test.

This sounds like an exercise to get you to do a number of statistical tests, but if this was something in real life my first thought would be to work out why you really cared about running a data mining exercise, perhaps reduce this to a value in terms of money, and then look for the test that represented that best.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The tasks performance measure is always the total cost. I am running a number of algorithms (15) on a number of customer-centered problems (9), e.g. fraud detection. As I am using WEKA, McNemar and 5x2CV cannot be used as they would have to used "within" the algorithms (to directly compare the result for each instance) and WEKA does not support them. Thus, I can only use the aggregate metric 'total cost' and would have 10xtotal cost for 10 iterations on different random subsamples. Do you find Wilcoxon an appropriate measure in that case? The sign-test is very weak.

Comment: Just to clarify: Output is 2x (two algorithms) 10x (10 iterations using subsamples < entire dataset) total cost.

Comment: You seem to be looking for per-instance results so that you can pair up results for each instance in a test that assumes that each pair is independent. This is a very strong assumption because all the pairs in a particular run come from the same split of training vs test samples which has led to the same set of fitted model parameters - I think this is what http://www.public.asu.edu/~huanliu/dmml_presentation/T-test.pdf calls random variability due to choice of training set. If you can get by with summaries of each entire run you can probably get all you need from the experiment output file.

Comment: I don't really have much applicable practical experience in this area, but my inclination would be to get as much data as possible - using multiple data sets if necessary to keep the per data set size representative and using overnight runs if required. Then minor quibbles or inefficiencies in the analysis are made irrelevant by the sheer volume of data analysed - if there is enough data to drive tail probs into scientific notation you can stop worrying about statistical significance and start worrying about the practical importance of the difference you have worked out so accurately.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am actually running overall 15 algorithms on 9 data sets an plan on using Friedman and Neymar later on for the more interesting results/conclusions in case they (hopefully) turn up. The direct comparison of only two algorithms is rather to get a first feeling whether some data preprocessing is a good choice or even has an influence. I guess I'll use all three (Resampled t-test + Cohen's Kappa as still often applied, the sign-test on resampled subsets as found to show an at least "considerably lower type I error" and finally Wilcoxon as the violation of the

Comment: independent domains assumptions isn't violated as badly as usually assumed when rendering it infeasible as I use 1/3 subsamples for 7/9 datasets. Even though I'll still have to investigate some more on Wilcoxon. But as I said, just to get a first picture of how some choices turn out. Does that procedure seem okay to you?

Comment: I suspect that you know more about both theory and practice than I do in this area, so I shouldn't be trying to answer these but here is one idea anyway - if you write a program to generate data at random obeying a model similar to what you think is going on or what your predictors/classifiers assume is going on then you know the correct answer and you have no possible shortage of data. You can then try out evaluation schemes on this fake data and see if the answers it gets are usually correct and reasonably stable. It looks like this is what the pdf slides above might have been based on.